# Method help in Java

Tags: java, methods

Below is my code.  When I am trying to call the positive or negative Triangle it throws errors.  Please help!

Here are some of the errors 
method negativeTriangle in class method cannot be applied to given types;
required: String, int, int
found: no arguments 
reason: actual and formal arguments list differ in length

method positiveTriangle in class method cannot be applied to given types;
required: String, int
found: no arguments 
reason: actual and formal arguments list differ in length

")" expected 
";" expected
not a statement
";" expected 
cannot find symbol
symbol: variable String
location: class main

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        purpose();

        gettingPrintCharacter();

        gettingVarifyingInputs();

        positiveTriangle(String aChar, int amount));

        negativeTriangle(String aChar, int amount, int opposite);


    }

    public static void purpose() {  
        System.out.print("This program will print a right triangle. \nThe "
           + "character that is entered at the prompt will be used to print"
           + " a right triangle.  \nThe value that is entered at the prompt "
           + "will be the right triangle's height and width.  \nIf the value "
           + "is negative only an outline of the triangle will be printed "
           + "else a filled in triangle will be printed.\n\n");
        //displays purpose of program 
    }

    public static void gettingPrintCharacter(){
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the character to be used: ");
        String triangle = keyboard.next();
        //converts character(s) entered into string
        char aChar = triangle.charAt(0);
        //slects only the first character of the string
        //the string above is to "idiot" or accident prof if they enter 
        //more than one character
    }

    public static void gettingVarifyingInputs(){
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        int amount;
        boolean valid= false;
        while (!valid)//first loop unitl uers inputs correct value
        {// starts the main loop
            System.out.print("Enter a non-zero integer length (+/-1 through +/-16): ");
            amount = keyboard.nextInt();// length and width of triangle
            while(amount == 0 || amount >16 || amount <-16)// invalid input tester
            {// starts second loop for user to input correct value
                System.out.print("Input value outside of range");
                System.out.print("\nEnter a non-zero integer length (+/-1 through +/-16): ");
                amount = keyboard.nextInt();// length and width of triangle
            }// ends loop
            valid = true;// end user input loop
        }
    }

    public static void positiveTriangle(String aChar, int amount){

        int i = 1;
        int j = i;
        do { //first do loop
            do{//second do loop
                System.out.print(aChar);
                j++;
            }while (j<=i);//second while loop end
            System.out.println();
            i++;
            j=1;
        }while(i<=amount);//first while loop end
    }//ends last else 

    public static void negativeTriangle(String aChar, int amount, int opposite) {

        opposite = Math.abs(amount);//finds absolute value
        for (int i = 0; i <= opposite; i++) {// first negative loop
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) { // second negative loop  
                if (i == opposite) { 
                    for (int k = 0; k<= opposite; k++)// third negative loop
                        System.out.print("*");//prints for right outside of triangle
                    break;//  ends third negative loop
                } 
                else if (i > 1) {
                    System.out.print("*");          
                    for (int k = 0; k < i - 1; k++)// fourth negative loop
                        System.out.print(" ");
                    System.out.print("*"); 
                    break;// end fouth negative loop                  
                } else //else to print outside of triangle
                    System.out.print("*");//prints for right outside of triangle
            } // restarts the negative  second loop
            System.out.println();
        }// restarts the negative first loop
    }// ends loop    
}
```

---

Comment: Please read about how to call a method in Java.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call the method like this:

```
positiveTriangle(String aChar, int amount));
negativeTriangle(String aChar, int amount, int opposite);
```

Actually you need to pass a valid arguments (values) in order to call methods.

```
positiveTriangle("A", 5);
negativeTriangle("A", 6, 1);
```

This Link will help you to understand [Java Methods](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_methods.htm)

**[Edit]**

You need to get the nChar and amount values from your already declared methods, so you need to tell your methods to return the generate value just like:

```
public static String gettingPrintCharacter() { <- here you need to specify the return type of your method.
    //your current code
    return aChar; <- this line should be the last line in you method
}
```

Also:

```
public static int gettingVarifyingInputs(){
    //your current code
    return amount;
}
```

Then you can simply do in your main method:

```
String aChar = gettingPrintCharacter();
int amount = gettingVarifyingInputs();

positiveTriangle(aChar, amount);
negativeTriangle(aChar, amount, 0);
```

Comment: So how do I get a String and int variable to go to the method?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid way to call a method:

```
positiveTriangle(String aChar, int amount)); //Also not extra ')' here

negativeTriangle(String aChar, int amount, int opposite);
```

You need to call like this:

```
positiveTriangle("SomeString", 0);   //Pass the actual value here, this is just a example

negativeTriangle("SomeString", 0, 0);
```